# Firefox ignores layout.css.text-decoration-skip-ink.enabled=false setting

Tags: firefox, text-formatting, css

Since today, my Firefox browser decided to start ignoring the aforementioned *about:config* setting which removes the horrible "new" & "stylish" underline look.

In other words: `layout.css.text-decoration-skip-ink.enabled = false`  - does *not* work for me anymore.

This "new" & "stylish" way looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dVur.png
(which is unacceptable, look at the mess near that comma)

I want my unbroken line back, please. Is there any other way to do that apart from the ignored setting?
Maybe someone can point me to a userstyle for something like Stylish extension that will fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several people have already remarked that Firefox 86 has dropped support for the
`layout.css.text-decoration-skip-ink.enabled` preference in this release
([example post](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/ltv9ys/layoutcsstextdecorationskipinkenabled_alternative/)).

A workaround was proposed to add to the `userContent.css` file this line:

```
text-decoration-skip-ink: none !important
```

References:

- [Mozilla text-decoration-skip-ink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink)
- [Mozilla UserContent.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserContent.css&printable=yes)

Comment: Thanks! I added `html {text-decoration-skip-ink: none !important}` to my Stylus and got those perfect lines back.